# Cannot search for artifact in Eclipse Kepler using m2e plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, eclipse-kepler

I tried the new Eclipse Kepler that already comes with a maven plugin.

But when I want to add a dependency (open the pom.xml, go to dependencies tab and click add) I can input some string like "jetty" in the search box but nothing happens. In older versions I got a list of all dependencies containing "jetty".

I don't know if this is important but I directly get an info when opening the "add dependency screen":
"Artifact Id cannot be empty".

I do not use a proxy or have any network issues.

I also missed an information something like: "indexing maven repo..."

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had similar situation and by googling for a while i found out that this is most likely because your central Repository index might never have been updated.
For this what you can do is

1. Go to **Window > Show View > Other >** type Maven in filter and select **Maven Repositories**.
2. In **Maven Repositories** tab Expand **Global Repositories**, Right-click on **central** and **Update Index**.

also you can set up index to update on eclipse startup **Windows > Preferences > Maven** and check **"Download repository index updates on startup"**.

Hope this helps some one else.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this view at all. This seems like the correct way to solve the problem (not my suggestion / finding).

Comment: For step 2, how long would "Update Index" typically take? Its taking over an hour for me and eclipse it just chugging and clock blocking

Answer (score 10):

**Windows** > **Preferences** > **Maven** and check "**Download repository index updates on startup**".

Restart and you're all fixed.

Comment: Yup that solves it. Just let it finish downloading the index updates when you start it (it will say "downloading index updates" or something along these lines at the bottom right corner).

Answer (score 4):

Very strange but now it worked using the following way:

1. Add some dependency directly in the pom.xml
2. Save the pom.xml to trigger the change. Now the library added directly appears in the project.
3. Now I also got messages in the status bar like "indexing... " and "searching repository"
4. I am now able to add an dependency using the method from the question. It now retrieves a list of artifacts of which I can choose.

Maybe a bug as also the add dialog should trigger the first repository search/indexing.

The information: "Artifact Id cannot be empty" still appears and had nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by going to Window > Show View > Other > Maven > Maven Repositories

Expand global repositories right click central > Rebuild index (wait for it)
When it finishes
Expand local repositories and do the same for the local repository (rebuild index)
If you encounter some error simply try again. It worked for the second time and now i can search maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

Another gotcha is that it won't start searching until you've entered several characters

1. nz.ac
2. com.mi
3. junit

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem! It is because you do not have STS (Spring Tool Suite) installed. Go to Marketplace install it and it is gonna work!

Answer (score 0):

I did "In Maven Repositories tab Expand Global Repositories, Right-click on central and Update Index", it did not work, then click left expand triangle, it ran, and wait for while.  Now it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have done what Yogi and erasmus77 said but after all the message "Artifact Id cannot be empty" remained. So **I ignored the message** and I wrote the dependency in the search bar and then results appeared!

Thank you for this question!

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help someone... I had the same problem, tried to fix it doing all the steps everyone is mentioning in the other answers and I couldn't fix it like that. In the end, the solution was to **delete the content of the settings.xml** file in my **.m2** folder. For some reason, it was using a different global repository, not the default maven one. After that, I got the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same issue. I followed all of the suggestion above and the problem persisted. Then I opened the "Local Repository", right click on the "Local Repository" sub link>rebuild index. That fixed the issue. So, if "Rebuild Index" on the "Global Repository/central" doesn't work, try "Rebuild Index" on the "Local Repository/Local Repository"