# Cannot add dependency in maven project in eclipse kepler version

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, git, maven

I am using eclipse kepler version. This version of eclipse already comes with a maven plugin. I tried to add a dependency by going to pom.xml and then going to dependencies tab and then clicking on add. I then input some spring like springframework in the search box but nothing happens. I don't get any list of dependencies. I do not have any network issues.

I then clicked on `window > show view > Other` and typed maven in filter and selected maven repositories. In maven repositories I then expanded global repositories and right clicked there and clicked update index. Nothing happened. That did not solve my problem. Then I again right clicked on global repositories and clicked rebuild index. But it remained on 0%. I mean rebuilding index remained at 0%. I waited for a long time. But still the progress bar showed 0%. It does not increase. I even clicked update and rebuild index on local repositories but that also did not solve my problem.

Then somebody told me to click on window and go to preferences and click maven. And then check `Download repository index updates on startup`. I went to preferences and clicked maven, but the problem is I could not find the `Download repository index updates on startup` option there. The option is not there. I searched clearly but the option is not there. Now, I don't know what should I do. I have been trying for many days to solve this problem, but till now I have have not been to do so. This problem is giving me stress. Can anyone please give me a solution.

Comment: Hope you followed this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doent-work I had similar issue from past 2months when I moved from juno to kepler. I followed the solution and got my problems solved. Another thing is that before you start you can delete the repository and then start over again with those steps( sometimes when downloading the dependency, repository may get corrupted). Quick way to check if your repository is fine or not just try to search dependencies which are already present in your local repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot KaPra.I found the solution.I found the "Download repository index updates on startup" option.Its on window>Preferences>Maven itself.Just by double clicking on maven a list comes out.I checked "Download repository index updates on startup" and restarted eclipse.It worked for me.