# maven not searching(gui not working)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using eclipse juno and maven plugin. I had a problems with maven at the begin after installation - it wasn't working. I marked an option "Download repository index updates on startup" and everything was fine. Now after week i try to search for some jars and it's not working again. Option with download on startup is still marked. I tried also : 
In Maven Repositories tab Expand Global Repositories, Right-click on central and Update Index.
I updated Index, rebuilded it. 
One thing - when i add to pom.xml for example

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's getting downloaded and looks fine, but GUI doesn't work

Comment: What is the exact problem you're seeing? For example, if I said to you "my computer doesn't work" what would you recommend? However, if I said "my computer doesn't turn on", or "my computer turns on, but I can't type with the keyboard", would you recommend the same, or different things?

Comment: When i try to type something in select dependency window for example "springframework" it's not searching, nothing happens. It was working before

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: i can't, i need 10 reputation to add a picture. Just Create new Maven project, click pom.xml, open a tab dependencies and click add and new window will pop up. And there is a field "Enter groupId, arifactID or sha1 prefix or patern(*)" And there i enter "springframework" and under it there is a search results, and i get nothing, the area with result is empty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work   simillar problem, but it didin't work for me this time