# Need to get updated maven archetype catalog inside Eclipse - Maven Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, spring-tool-suite

As trying out to learn new things, I have configured external Maven 3.3.9 to my eclipse.

When I am creating a maven web application using Eclipse **new Maven Project -> Select an Archetype** I could find that existing ArtifactId from **the ecplise maven Archetype catalog** is of ***maven-archetype-webapp - version 1.0***

if I proceed with this, I get a project structure with web.xml that is below

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

and not up to date with the latest **

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
```

also the **JRE is pointing 1.5**

Please find the screenshot:[image: Screenshot of the Maven project structure I was referring]

I believe if i am using the latest **maven-archetype-webapp** could resolve this problem, If not please correct me.

I wonder how to update this catalog list of archetype version to match the latest Webapp and its structure.

**Should I upload it from some remote catalog? or after the project structure is created. I should manually change the JRE and other things manually?**

Can any one please guide me with steps to do this. I will be really thankful.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to update your remote repositories indexes.

There are a few ways to do it. On menu Window -> Preferences -> Maven check the option 'Download repository index updates on startup'. Restart Eclipse and see if indexes are being updated. In other way: open 'Maven Repositories' window. Then click on 'central' repository and use the options 'Update index' and 'Rebuild index'.

Later you should found the lastest Archetypes from Maven Central when you create a new Maven Project from Archetype.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063863/597200

Comment: How do you open the Maven Repositories window? Where is that located?

Answer (score 0):

The archetypes that show up in Eclipse are from maven.org. Generally, I would think that the latest versions of the archetype have been pushed to maven.org, so you should be getting the latest files. If you can track down the source code, then you can check. Typically, for an archetype, the location of the source files will be in the pom.xml file, so look in there. Since the archetype is hosted on [Maven Central](http://marven.org), you can look at the pom.xml file by looking up the archetype by it's groupId and artifactId there.

If you want to change the archetype's files, you will need to contact the author of the archetype and suggest a change. If the archetype is from github.com, for example, you could fork the archetype, make the change, and request a pull. You could also submit a bug/issue report. If the archetype's author does not have the archetype in open source, perhaps they run a bug reporting site for their products, like a jira.

Finally, of course, you can write you own archetype and upload it to [The Central Repository](http://central.sonatype.org/) yourself.

EDIT: It doesn't matter what version of Maven you are using, Eclipse will get the archetype list from maven.org by default. See [How does the Archetype Plugin know about archetypes?](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html).

Comment: thanks for your knowledge. I want to know, how can i get other achetype on that catalog list ? where and how do we configure them? for getting the latest Java Web application structure.

Comment: You get an exhaustive list when you do Eclipse->New Maven Project->Next (to Select archetype). Please accept answer if it helps.

Comment: So the point is what ever is there in that exhaustive list, will generate a project package structure. And for an Java Web Application, if i am selecting maven-archetype-webapp from catalog, this will give me a Project structure with JRE version 1.5 by default and web.xml of the old version which i have mentioned.

Comment: Sure. If you look on maven.org you will see that the archetype is from 2006. It's 10 years old. There are newer ones on there. If you are using wildfly or glassfish, for example, look for some of their archetypes.

Comment: Dear Nicholas i faced lot of problem after i tried changing the JRE and web.xml if possible can you advise me for the question i posted on this [link - I posted ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056485/eclipse-or-spring-suit-error-maven-project-dynamic-web-module-cannot-be-chan)