# Eclipse or Spring Suit Error - Maven Project - Dynamic Web module cannot be changed to 3.1

Tags: eclipse, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have configure external Maven 3.9 to spring tool suit.

I did all possible way what was mentioned in different post from stackover flow but failed to overcome below error **Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1**

Can any one please help me to resolve it.

[image: Screen-shot saying Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1]

I will give you the steps I did to create the Maven Project.

1. New -> Maven Project -> Selected maven-arcetype-webapp

**

[image: Screenshot of maven-archetype I selected]

2. As some blog suggested updated the web.xml to latest 3.1
3. Changed the System Library from 1.5 to 1.8
4. Still when i try to change the Dynamic Web Module in project facet, its gives me the error I shared.

Even some blogs suggested me to change the xml file from navigator view of project facet. After which if i do an **Maven -> Update Project. Again things get worse**.

It gives me below error.

[image: After making an Maven update it gives me below error]

I am really fed up to find a solution have done enough research. Please any one help me on this.

I want a Maven Project with JRE 1.8 with Project Facet - Web module 3.1 without any error.

And also if I take a Maven update project (The JRE should not change to 1.5 which is really annoying)

Comment: Naresh, might I suggest you mark the answer as accepted as it does work.  It helps the robots not push this question to the top as unaswered

Answer (score 2):

Go to `properties` of you project , in `Project Facets`.
The Window on the right, select `Runtimes` : then you will have your JRE (JRE 7 or 8) check the box and you will have it in the left the box checked `Java` : choose your version of Java : 1.8 and you'll see that `Dynamic Web Module` will disappear. After that uncheck the choosen runtime `jre` and the  `Dynamic Web Module` will reappear . here you have to choose your version 3.1 without the error then -> `Apply`  `OK`