# Eclipse: Maven search dependencies doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have the same problem as the person who post this:

[Eclipse : Maven search dependencies doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work)

When I try to search a dependency  it just doesn't work. But the solution given in the post above it didn't work for me.

I have tried so many things, Updating indexes, Rebuilding, and it took very, very long time for updating and rebuilding, it looked like it was never going to stop, but after all it has stopped and it's still not working.

I am really desperate and I don't know what to do to solve my problem. If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful.

Comment: does executing `mvn clean install` on your parent directory gives you some error?

Comment: This is very vague. What class are you searching, what's your set-up, how are you searching it, what is your Eclipse and M2E version? Did you clean and update the Maven project?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS` @nullpointer

Comment: I am searching for Spring dependencies. My M2E version is 1.5.0 (m2e includes Incubating components). My Eclipse version is Luna 4.4.0 @Tunaki

Comment: is this a multi-module projects ? With a parent structure perhaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also had a similar problem, the only thing that solved it was to start over step-by-step with this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html

I hope it helps you too

Another thing is that in my maven project Run Configuration -> JRE I changed the default to "Alternate JRE" and selected my jdk1.8.0_25 - this was also an important step to make it work

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)