# How to enable search in add dependency in latest version of m2e maven integration

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Latest update of m2e plugin changed how indexing works and the method described in [Eclipse : Maven search dependencies doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work) will not work, since Maven Repositories View is marked for removal and no longer supports index rebuild functions.

And now searching for artifacts does not work and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: In the _pom.xml_ tab, inside the `<dependencies>` element, typing `spring` and hitting Ctrl+Space works for me. Please name the m2e version you have (_latest_ is not a proper version number).

Comment: Wow, didn't know it could be used there in such a way. I will report it as a bug, since it does not work in Dependencies tab in Add dialog.

Comment: Thx for reporting: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/930 - In case you want to provide a pull request, you might have a look how [LemMinX-Maven](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx-maven) does it (maybe [this change](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#improved-lemminx-based-editor-with-newer-lemminx-maven) is related).