# repository index would not update, how do i fix this?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

The repository index will not download/update even though I have already [turned it on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76ucQ.png). I need to download it as the dependency search always keeps on getting zero results and it's getting really frustrating. I have already tried several solutions, none of which worked:

1. I have deleted my .m2 folder
2. I have already deleted my metadata folder.
3. I Uninstalled and re-downloaded m2eclipse.
4. I have already turned on the "Download repository index updates on startup" button.
5. I already tried to follow an old [stack overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work), but unfortunately, the "rebuild index" and "Full index enabled" no longer exists in my eclipse IDE.

Comment: Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder! That's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow that can cause data loss or wreck your workspace. Go to the `pom.xml` tab, inside the `<dependencies>` and type the search string and use code completion (Ctrl+Space) for searching.

Comment: 1) Are you working behind a proxy? 2) Are you able to navigate (or otherwise access) the repository in question, outside of Eclipse and the plugin?

Comment: Noted, i should've never deleted the metadata folder. 1. No i am not working behind a proxy. 2. Unfortunately, the only IDE I use is eclipse so i wont be able to answer that question.

Comment: Deleting the metadata folder is always a bad idea. Try `-clean` or a fresh workspace instead, but never ever delete the metadata folder. Please stop spreading this hoax which causes damage that cannot be reverted. For your issue see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73825422/6505250 and https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/930 (the functionality is currently broken at the place you looking for, but moved to a different place using the repository search API instead of downloading the index).

Comment: Understood, I got the solution from an older Stack Overflow post and didn't really think much of it, anyway, I would like to thank you for the advice and the time.

Comment: Did you find a solution - I have the same issue. Is the setting "rebuild index" gone? Or did it work when you deleted the .m2 folder and restarted eclipse?

Comment: @anmatr For a workaround and where you can help, see my comment above.

Comment: Unfortunately, no solutions are found, so i just manually put the dependency on the xml file.