# maven index not available in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

The searching dependency/plugins functions in eclipse doesn't work, I tried to use the suggested answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14059685/436559), but just found that the menu options are unavailable to my installation, why is that? see my context menu:

[image]

Comment: You can directly search for dependencies and Maven Plugins in the `pom.xml` tab via code completion by typing something in the `<dependencies>`/`<plugins>` section. Maven Central provides a search API which is faster than downloading an index. For performance reasons, Eclipse m2e has switched to the API in the `pom.xml` tab, but unfortunately in other places the switch is still not finished resulting in broken functionality at those other places. The mentioned answer is quite old and does not apply to current versions.

Comment: It would be great if you could mention what version you're on.

Comment: Oh sorry, the version my installation is `Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0) Build id: 20230907-1323`.